# clicking the hyperlink inside WPF listview is not selecting the corresponding row

Tags: wpf, listview, hyperlink, selection

I have following listview with a gridview column and cell template for that gridview column. But when I click on the "hyperlink", the corresponding gridview row is not getting selected.

Could anyone give me a solution please

**DATA TEMPLATE**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="smTemplate">
     <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SM}" />
        <TextBlock>
            <Hyperlink x:Name="tHLink" Click="thL_Click"      KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True">
                <TextBlock Text="TH" />
            </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>                   
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**LIST VIEW**

```
 <ListView Focusable="True">                
    <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="DM" CellTemplate="{StaticResource smTemplate}" />
       </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Whats in your thL_Click handler?

Comment: Am using that handler to set the visibility of another control.

Comment: Maybe try to set e.Handled = false inside your thl_Click.. i think that maybe your handler "eats" the mouse click. Or maybe setting IsHitTestVisible to false on the StackPanel.

Comment: i tried those...but of no luck :(

Comment: hey have got the solution..

Answer (score 1):

try changing `ListViewItem` style so when it gains keyboard focus it will be automatically selected:

```
<ListView>
   <!-- ..... -->
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus">
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                       <Storyboard>
                           <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                               <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                           </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                       </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Hyperlink` overrides `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` and `OnMouseLeftButtonUp`. In those methods, `e.Handled = true` is set *after* processing your event handlers, so you can't override it by attaching events to the control in XAML. In order to fix the behavior to suit your needs, you'll need to create a class derived from `Hyperlink` and override mouse handling events.

However, all this is unnecessary. Judging by you code, `Hyperlink` causes more problems than it solves, so I suggest replacing it with a single `TextBlock` control with a custom style.

```
<TextBlock Text="TH" TextDecorations="Underline" Cursor="Hand"
           Foreground="{x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackBrush}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Not a good answer]**
I find a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395376/getting-a-gridview-to-select-the-row-on-click-not-just-clicking-on-the-text?rq=1). and I just copied and pasted following code and I used it. its worked. even if you click on white blank , the corresponding row will be selected.

```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="rowStyle1">
                <Grid x:Name="backGroundPanel">
                    <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="backGroundPanel" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <Style x:Key="columnHeaderContianerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=rowStyle1}"/>
            </Style>
```

and I set property "ItemContainerStyle" of listview like code below:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource columnHeaderContianerStyle}" ... >
```

**[a revised answer]**
The above solution is not working if we are interested in capturing mouse in column control. because the rectangle in backGroundPanel capture mouse events ,then it prevents mouse events being captured by GridViewRowPresenter. so we must use a strategy that have 2 features:

1. Mouse events should be captured by inner column controls.
2. When user clicked every Where in the row, The row must be selected.

so, the solution get simpler this time. I used below code for my ListView's ItemContainerStyle.

```
<Style x:Key="columnHeaderContianerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">

            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseDown"></EventSetter>
        </Style>
```

and event Handler is :

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListViewItem)
        {
            ListViewItem s = (ListViewItem)sender;
            s.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

It works fine with 2 mentioned features.